# "docker rm" requires at least 1 argument

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy a container to a server via GitLab Pipeline.
Here is the code for the deployment stage:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY root@161.35.223.117 "
        docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS &&
        docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm &&
        docker run -d -p 5000:5000 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

When no docker container is running on the target server, the deployment stage yields the error: "docker rm" requires at least 1 argument. I don't get this error when i run the deployment stage code while a container is already running.

I assume that the argument, which container should be stopped, is empty and this is the cause for the error.

```
docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm &&
```

How can i change my script so that the docker rm-command only gets executed, when there is a container running?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the `--no-run-if-empty` (`-r`) option to your `xargs` invocation. See [the `xargs` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) for details.

Comment: Even though I'm not a fan  of using a pipe to` xargs` because I advocate for using the format flags, in this case `docker ps --filter status=exited -q | xargs -r docker rm` is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this command ?

```bash
docker stop container_name || true && docker rm container_name || true
```